# R - Error executing user-defined function

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I am trying to build a function that takes 2 arguments and uses those 2 arguments inside a replicate funtion

```
SPM <- function(bilhetes, N){
  total_bilhetes <- 12012000
  total_bilhetes_premios <- 3526450

  premios <- c(0,5,10,15,20,25,50,100,300,1000,27000,108000,288000)
  premios_bilhetes <- c(8485550,1895000,496800*2,88800*3,55200*4,16800*4,7920*6,5030*6,950*5,950,30,10,10)

  probs <- premios_bilhetes/total_bilhetes

  vector_ganhos <- c()
  ganho <- 0

  replicate(N, function(bilhetes) {
    total_bilhetes1 <- total_bilhetes
    premios_bilhetes1 <- premios_bilhetes
    probs1 <- probs

    for (i in c(1:bilhetes)) {
      A <- sample(x = premios,replace = T,size = 1, prob = probs1)
      ganho <- ganho - 5 + A

      if (A == 0) {
        premios_bilhetes1[1] <- premios_bilhetes1[1] - 1
      } else if (A == 5) {
        premios_bilhetes1[2] <- premios_bilhetes1[2] - 1
      } else if (A == 10) {
        premios_bilhetes1[3] <- premios_bilhetes1[3] - 1
      } else if (A == 15) {
        premios_bilhetes1[4] <- premios_bilhetes1[4] - 1
      } else if (A == 20) {
        premios_bilhetes1[5] <- premios_bilhetes1[5] - 1
      } else if (A == 25) {
        premios_bilhetes1[6] <- premios_bilhetes1[6] - 1
      } else if (A == 50) {
        premios_bilhetes1[7] <- premios_bilhetes1[7] - 1
      } else if (A == 100) {
        premios_bilhetes1[8] <- premios_bilhetes1[8] - 1
      } else if (A == 300) {
        premios_bilhetes1[9] <- premios_bilhetes1[9] - 1
      } else if (A == 1000) {
        premios_bilhetes1[10] <- premios_bilhetes1[10] - 1
      } else if (A == 27000) {
        premios_bilhetes1[11] <- premios_bilhetes1[11] - 1
      } else if (A == 108000) {
        premios_bilhetes1[12] <- premios_bilhetes1[12] - 1
      } else {
        premios_bilhetes1[13] <- premios_bilhetes1[13] - 1
      }

      total_bilhetes1 <- total_bilhetes1 - 1

      probs1 <- premios_bilhetes1/(total_bilhetes1)
    }

    vector_ganhos[length(vector_ganhos)+1] = ganho
  })
  return(vector_ganhos)
}
```

when I try to run it, e.g., `SPM(bilhetes = 5, N = 100)` I get:

```
Error in SPM(bilhetes = 5, N = 100) : could not find function "SPM"
```

I looked in another question and someone mentioned "sourcing" the function. I tried it, and this was the output:

```
> source("SPM")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
```

I'm rather new to R, so I'm probably making a dumb mistake.

Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you run the definiton of the function? Are there any errors running the definition of the function? The definition of the function runs for me without any error. Running `SPM(bilhetes = 5, N = 100)` I got the result `NULL` (also without any errors)

Comment: Hello and thanks for the welcome! 

When I run it I get

'SPM(bilhetes = 5, N = 100)'
'Error in SPM(bilhetes = 5, N = 100) : could not find function "SPM"

Maybe it's a problem of the system I'm working in

Comment: You need to copy and paste the function definition into the R console. Or, in RStudio, select the entire function and use "Run selected". Then try again. Using `source` is not correct, this sources a file and there is no file called "SPM". See `?source`, which you've already done because you know to look up basic documentation before asking us, right? ;-)

Comment: This post was not about the function `source`. I merely tried it because it was mentioned in another topic, and I was trying to debug the function in RStudio and it told me that I needed to source it before using breakpoints. Anyway, I did what you said (ran the entire function code), and it's working fine. Thanks!